# Android Studio freezes when I go to Settings

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I'm trying to learn Android development, specifically using Flutter. I'm using Android Studio 3.2 (Windows 10).

I was using Android Studio without issue for about a week. Then yesterday when I opened it some notification about an update popped up in the lower right (sorry, I cannot remember what the update was). I clicked "update".

Since then Android Studio still seems to function OK with one exception -- whenever I try to go to settings (File > Settings) it just freezes. I have to end the task using Task Manager.

Can anyone offer any way to fix this? I was making good progress and now dealng with Android Studio is taking up all my time. I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio...still freezes when I go to settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using system restore to restore your Computer to the time before the update

Comment: I don't have a restore point. Why would settings only be causing it to freeze? Where are the settings stored? Maybe I could delete them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED:** Adding this here in case anyone else experiences the same problem.

I deleted the config folder in `C:\Users\<some_user>\.AndroidStudio3.2` and restarted AS and it worked...was able to access File > Settings without freezing.

I had to reinstall Flutter/Dart plugins etc but that's fine. Just happy it is working again.